# Python/MySQL get data from table based on values in a dictionary

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a list of dictionaries of friends with the following structure

```
friendships = [{'name1': 'Joe Bloggs', 'name2': 'Jane Bloggs'},
{'name1': 'Joe Bloggs', 'name2': 'Jan Doe'},
{'name1': 'Another Name', 'name2': 'Someone Else'}]
```

I have a MySQL table with each person in called `People`. The structure of this table is

```
id, name
```

e.g.

```
1  Joe Bloggs
2  Jane Bloggs
3  Jan Doe
4  Another Name
5  Someone Else
```

I want to write an SQL query which will get me the ids of the friends from the table in a similar structure to what I have at the start e.g.

```
friendship_ids =  [{'id1': '1', 'id2': '2'},
{'id1': '1', 'id2': '3'},
{'id1': '4', 'id2': '5'}]
```

I currently do this by looping through each row in `friendships` and getting the ids that way but the list is quite large so wanted to do it with 1 query.

```
friendship_ids = []
for f in friendships
    cur.execute("SELECT (SELECT id FROM Person WHERE name = '%s') AS id1, (SELECT id FROM Person WHERE name = '%s') AS id2" % (f.name1, f.name2))
    d = cur.fetchone()
    friendship_ids.append(d)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you clarify? Is it this: `SELECT id from People` that will gett you all id:s.

Comment: Why don't you just create a second table in your database called `Friendships` and add your friendship data to it instead of mixing Python data structure with relational storage?

Comment: This seems more suitable for Django, even if you're not using it for a web app.

Comment: Ti me it seems that [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) or the [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) ORM (as mentioned by Edwin) could make your task way easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess if you really don't want a second table to store the friendships, you could use something like this:

```py
import itertools

# collect all the names involved
names = itertools.chain.from_iterables(f.values() for f in friendships)
query = 'SELECT name, id FROM People WHERE name in (%s)' \
             % ','.join(mysql_escape(n) for n in names)
```

Replace `mysql_escape` with some quoting facility of your MySQL driver. Then execute the queryand use the returned rows like this:

```py
# will contain a map from names to IDs
name_to_id = dict((row["name"], row["id"]) for row in rows)
```

You can then build your `friendship_ids` like this:

```py
friendship_ids = [{'id1': name_to_id[f['name1']], 'id2': name_to_id[f['name2']]}
                  for f in friendships]
```

Comment: thanks this was the answer i was after. However it turned out that running it over 1 query took more time than looping through and doing individual queries